# ASCII and isalpha if statement issue

Tags: c++, ascii

I am writing a program that takes a user inputted character, such as A, and a user inputted number, such as 7. The program checks the validity of the character, if true runs thru till it gets to this loop inside of a function. I am using ascii decimal for this loop inside of a function. This loop needs to check isalpha and if it is run the code inside the {}'s, it's doing that correctly. The else is not working the way I want and am not sure how to correct it. I need the else (is not alpha) to add a 1 back to the counter in the loop and increase the ascii by 1. If I run it as so, it gives off a retry/ignore/abort error. If I run it without the num++; it runs and stops after the loop ends. So, if you put in a Z and choose 3, it runs thru the loop 3 times and outputs just a Z. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I need it to output something like: Input: Z Input: 4 it should output: Z A B C to the screen. It needs to ignore other ascii non alpha characters.

Thanks

```
string buildSeries(char A, int num)
{
//builds the output with the info the
//user inputted
stringstream str1;
string outted;
int DeC=(int)A, i = 0;

//loop builds the output
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{


        if (isalpha(DeC))
        {
            //converts the decimal to a letter
            str1<<(char)DeC;
            //adds a space
            str1<<" ";
            //increases the decimal
            DeC++;
        }
        else
        {
        num++;
        DeC++;
        }


}

    //builds the sstream and puts it in
    //variable "outted"
    outted = str1.str();


return outted;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you need to loop back to 'A' at Z change your `DeC++` to

```
if DecC == 'Z'
    DecC = 'A'
else
    DecC++;
```

Or you could get fancy and use the modulus operator

*Edit*

I think the problem may be that this [stringstream insertion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), >>, doesn't have an overload that handles a char.  It's converting the char to a short or an int then inserting it.  Try using [string::append(size_t size, char c)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) instead.  That should handle inserting a char.

That is replace you calls to `str1<<(char)DeC;` with `outted.append(1, (char)DeC)` and remove your use of the string stream

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it's still showing the other non-alpha characters. I'll look up the mod and see if I can apply that here.

Comment: Doing it this way is _much_ better than using modulus, unless a) performance is _amazingly_ important and/or b) you speak in math(s). This does what the OP want (assuming the initial condition is right, i.e. Dec is in the A-Z range to start with, and is readable by humans.

Comment: I used some of what you were saying sh301 and got it working like this: for(i=0;i<num;i++)
 {


    //converts the decimal to a letter
    str1<<(char)DeC;
    //adds a space
    str1<<" ";
    //increases the decimal
    /*DeC++;*/

    if(DeC==(int)'Z')
    {
    DeC = (int)'A';
    }
    else if (DeC == (int)'z')
    {
    DeC = (int)'a';
    }
    else
    {
    DeC++;
    }

 }

Answer (score 0):

What is DeC? The phrase "ascii list" makes me suspect it's a 'C' string, in which case you are calling isAlpha() on the pointer not on the value in the string.

edit: If for example you have

```
char DeC[40];

// read in a string form somewhere

// DeC is a pointer to some memory it has a value of a 32 or 64bit number
if ( isAlpha(DeC) {

// what you might have meant is 
if ( isAlpha(*DeC) { // the character value at the current position in DeC
```

Comment: im using the decimal list for ascii, like 65 is A, 66 is B, etc. the DeC is a variable that holds the user inputted character in it, the isalpha(DeC) checks that variable for an alpha character and if so runs the code in the braces. Hope that helps, first time using you guys, but have gotten a lot of good information here. Much thanks for looking.

Comment: should I put in the entire function? Didn't want to overload this question with code. Just can't get the else to give the results I want.

Comment: It's not letting me post the entire code here, ill edit my initial post with the function.

Comment: I am not using pointers at this point or referencing memory locations or anything such as that. This is pretty basic code with a few files; CharFunc.h, CharFunc.cpp, and driver.cpp. My functions are in the CharFunc.cpp, the CharFunc.h is my prototypes, and the driver.cpp is my main that I am just calling 5 different functions from while passing values back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for everyone trying to understand this and helping, I know reading others code is difficult to understand if ya can't see it all and know what it's trying to do. If I can just get the else to add a 1 back to the counter and move the ascii decimal forward each time I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it working with a modified version of shf301's idea. Very crude, but it's not rocket science lol... Much appreciation for all that tried to help me. Great site, great people.